# Get Jest to test the CSS styles of an element in Angular

Tags: css, angular, unit-testing, jestjs, styles

I wrote a test with Karma and Jasmine in an Angular project that can tell if an element is showing as required - that works great - but the company has decided to switch to Jest and none of the tests work.

Does anyone know how to get the following to work in Jest?

```
it('required checkbox label should be blue', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    //----------------- is the label blue?
    const e = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("p-checkbox[required] > label")).nativeElement;
    expect(getComputedStyle(e).color).toEqual('rgb(39, 109, 226)');
});
```

The returned test is:

```
 ComponentsComponent
√ should create the app (1457 ms)
× buttons should be blue (1270 ms)

  ● ComponentsComponent › buttons should be blue
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: "rgb(39, 109, 226)"
Received: ""

  159 |     fixture.detectChanges();
  160 |     const e = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".p-button")).nativeElement;
> 161 |     expect(getComputedStyle(e).backgroundColor).toEqual('rgb(39, 109, 226)');
      |                                                 ^
  162 |   });
  163 |
  164 | });

  at src/app/features/components/components/components.component.spec.ts:161:49
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:407:30)
  at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:3765:43)
  at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:406:56)
  at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:167:47)
  at Object.wrappedFunc (node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:4250:34)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? If so please add an answer and I'll upvote!

Comment: any solutions yet?